# WARNING: Unknown module: <...> specified to --patch-module

Tags: java

I have 2 files:

```
src/metron_core/Metron_Core.java
src/metron_core/module-info.java
```

Metron_Core.java:

```java
package metron_core;

public class Metron_Core {
    
    static public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello from metron core");
    }
    
}
```

module-info.java:

```java
module metron_core {
    
}
```

I compile to class files using:

```sh
cd "$start_dir"
javac --module-path mods -d bin_test \
        src/metron_core/module-info.java src/metron_core/Metron_Core.java
```

This creates:

```
bin_test/metron_core/Metron_Core.class
bin_test/module-info.class
```

Then I create jar using:

```sh
cd "$start_dir"
jar -v --create --file=mods/metron_core@1.0.jar \
        --module-version=1.0 -C bin_test .
```

This successfully creates `mods/metron_core@1.0.jar`.
I want to use this with `--patch-module`.
`"vmArgs": "--patch-module java.base=${workspaceFolder}/bin_agent --patch-module metron_core=${workspaceFolder}/mods"`.

Note I added `--patch-module` two times.

When I run I get:

`WARNING: Unknown module: metron_core specified to --patch-module`.

I have no clue what to do.